# match rows across two columns

Tags: r, duplicates, match

Given a data frame

```
df=data.frame(
              E=c(1,1,2,1,3,2,2), 
              N=c(4,4,10,4,3,2,2)
              )
```

I would like to create a third column: Every time a value equals another value in the same column and these rows are also equal in the other column it results in a match (new character for every match).

```
dfx=data.frame(
               E=c(1,1,2,1,3,2,2,3, 2), 
               N=c(4,4,10,4,3,2,2,6, 10),
               matched=c("A", "A", "B","A", NA, "C", "C", NA, "B")
               )
```

Thanks!

Comment: What are the rules for matching? Why do 1 and 4 result in A?

Comment: Sorry, I should have elaborated. Every time a value equals another value in the same column and these rows are also equal in the other column it results in a match (new character for every match).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, `df` is:

```
df <- structure(list(E = c(1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2), N = c(4, 4, 
        10, 4, 3, 2, 2, 6, 10)), .Names = c("E", "N"), row.names = c(NA, 
        -9L), class = "data.frame")
```

You can do:

```
dfx <- transform(df, matched = {
  i <- as.character(interaction(df[c("E", "N")]))
  tab <- table(i)[order(unique(i))]
  LETTERS[match(i, names(tab)[tab > 1])]
})

#   E  N matched
# 1 1  4       A
# 2 1  4       A
# 3 2 10       B
# 4 1  4       A
# 5 3  3    <NA>
# 6 2  2       C
# 7 2  2       C
# 8 3  6    <NA>
# 9 2 10       B
```